# Programmatically press a button in another appplication's activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Task manager on Motorola Droid3 shows a popup to ask the user whether to close a running application or not.
I need to programmatically answer "no" to that Activity. Is that feasible?

A more generic question: is it possible to "register" my application to catch the event of the opening of another's application activity and automatically press a button on that activity?

Thank-you

Comment: Why in the world do you need to do this?

Comment: please read the post to know it

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible. If that was possible, then each application could control device as if it was user. For example in this case such application could enable Mobile Data in Settings, but only system applications are allowed to do this.

Comment: Actually you can enable mobile data but only on Android 2.2 and down. In 2.3 they removed this workaround.

Comment: If you check: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/01/generating-keypresses-programmatically.html you will see that the answer is  not as easy as it looks.

Comment: How can system app do this. @inazaruk can you share something you know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to figure out why the task manager is trying to close your application.

Make sure that you are not running any blocking tasks on the UI thread (like downloading or copying a file).

Comment: So you mean to say that your application is doing CPU intensive work?

Comment: Yes I know why: because my application is running for more than 45 mins in idle mode. The task manager istalled on Droid3 asks the user whether he wants to close it or not. I have contacted motorola and they say that maybe in the future they will add a way to put new applications in the white-list (so far the white-list is hardcoded)

Comment: No it does not use CPU intensivelly. It is enough to have an application in idle mode for more than 45 mins.