# Programmatically enter secret code like *#*#4636#*#* on Android

Tags: android

On many Android devices you can get into a secret settings menu from Phone app by typing in

*#*#4636#*#*

https://web.archive.org/web/20140205002205/http://technology-headlines.com:80/2010/09/17/4636-android-secret-codes/

There are also some other codes.

Is it also possible to open this stuff programmatically?

I've tried this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);    
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*#*#4636#*#*"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But it just tries to initiate a phone call and of course fails, hangs up and closes the Phone app.

EDIT: The phone *#*#4636#*#* gets saved to my Contact list as "Unknown" but the call just fails. In fact, the secret code only works when you type manually on buttons in Phone app without pressing Call in the end. Is it probably just a hidden feature of Phone app which has nothing to do with calling?
If so, one could open the Phone app programmatically and simulate typing on the buttons.

According to this post
[Programmatically press a button in another appplication's activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954711/programmatically-press-a-button-in-another-appplications-activity)

this should NOT be possible because if any app on non-rooted phone could just start other apps and press something there, it could take over control of the whole device and do bad things.

Here are some more details but I guess the post is a bit old and even if it worked it may have been changed in current Android versions:
http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.de/2009/01/generating-keypresses-programmatically.html

So, no easier way to enter secret code?

Comment: may be using ACTION_DIAL instead? it would not call, only send you to the dialer?

Comment: excellent! it works. Could you pls type that into an answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Is it also possible to open this stuff programmatically?*

**Yes**:

```
    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    in.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TestingSettings");
    startActivity(in);
```

You just need to watch logcat output to learn what this magic combination actually opens:

> I/ActivityManager(31362): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.settings/.TestingSettings} from pid
>   4257

Comment: thx, this worked), so in total there are 3 working solutions: 1) ACTION_DIAL, 2) ACTION_MAIN + TestingSettings, 3) broadcast Telephony.SECRET_CODE

Comment: Consider tablets that don't have telephony or dialer. Then this approach is probably most reliable.

Comment: is there a way to directly open the "phone information" activity in the testing settings?

Comment: Even i tried same thing but its not working do  i need to add any thing in manifest file.

Answer (score 22):

Secret codes exist and work independent of the dialer application. The dialer application just provides a handy interface for these codes. It recognizes the special string and then calls a special intent to invoke the action. You shouldn't use the dialer to call these dialogs. Instead you can call the secret codes directly yourself like the dialer does internally:

**Invoking built in secret codes:**

What the dialer really does when you enter the code is extracting the number between *#*# and #*#* and then broadcasting the following intent:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE", Uri.parse("android_secret_code://4636")));
```

**Register your own secret codes (if you like)**:

You can even register your own secret code actions using:

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" /> 
<data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="4636" />
```

Source: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=422

**Edit:** Fixed a bug in the original code (see comment)

Comment: Throws "no activity to handle intent" on my unrooted HTC Desire, but with some modifications this works: sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE", Uri.parse("android_secret_code://4636")));

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
String ussdCode = "*" +Uri.encode ("#")+"*"+Uri.encode ("#")+ "4636" + Uri.encode ("#")+"*"+Uri.encode ("#")+"*";
startActivity (new Intent ("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse ("tel:" + ussdCode)));
```

finally you must encode '#' using `Uri.encode()`

Comment: Hmm tried and the same result. Probably it now enters the code itself better than without encoding, but looks like these whole secret codes are not triggered by a call, but instead by manual typing on buttons

Answer (score 3):

`ACTION_DIAL` sends the user to the dialer with the given code (it does not call). So that would be :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);    
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*#*#4636#*#*"));
startActivity(intent);
```

It would appear that codes are to be *dialed*, rather than to be *called*

Comment: Good idea, but I think it's a bit fragile solution, because it depends on the dialer parsing the string and then calling the intent instead of calling the intent directly.

Answer (score 0):

looking for this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$TestingSettingsActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different activities for different phone, we can jump to the activity through typing in *#*#4636#*#*.
And use

> adb shell dumsys activity activities

to find the realActivity package and  name.
e.g: Xiaomi 8

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$TestingSettingsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```