# How can I dial secret code for Service Menu from my activity?

Tags: android, uri

If I call from a normal dialer this code, *#*#197328640#*#* it takes me to the service menu of the android but when I am dialing it from my activity it is saying "USSD Code Rejected", I am using ACTION_CALL in the intent with URL String = "tel:XXXXXXXXXX" (where XXXX is the code)... I want to know how can I open the service from within my activity?

Comment: do u want to make make call from your activity?

Comment: i want to open service menu from my activity. Which normally opens from the dialer. the simple dial number code is not working from the activity...try this in your dialer if you have android phone *#*#197328640#*#*

Comment: I think action_call is intended to pass contact no only hence it takes the code as an contact no and you get error..i suppose you will have to use `ACTION_CALL_BUTTON` to open appropriate screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically enter secret code like \*#\*#4636#\*#\* on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769166/programmatically-enter-secret-code-like-4636-on-android)