# How to execute secret Android code in source code?

Tags: android

I don't know how to call Android secret code such as *#06# in Android source. I try using ACTION_CALL and ACTION_DIAL but it's not effective.

I hope you will give me a solution. Thanks a lots.

Comment: OP: Please state what android version are you trying to do this on?

Comment: I's using android 2.3.6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically enter secret code like \*#\*#4636#\*#\* on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769166/programmatically-enter-secret-code-like-4636-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

The data intent Uri scheme is similar to `tel://*#06#` in encoded form...but having said that, there has been fixes made to prevent the exploit from formatting your handset as was in the case of Samsung.

The fix involves filtering the Uri and if it contains that said scheme, it will reject it, something to bear in mind!

Older handsets were easily exploited for those versions earlier then ICS, but with the availability of the fix available on the market to intercept said Uri intent. Newer versions of Android has that patched in.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk That's true, yes, there was patent issues surrounding it, but in the context of my answer explaining it affected Samsung models which enabled to wipe the handset upon clicking on a linky on some web site...hence it was "exploitable" :)

Comment: http://www.androidcentral.com/ussd-test, or even the keywords '*samsung ussd exploit*' there was a direct dial code similar to `*#06#`, one of the service codes to wipe/factory reset and it was linkified on a website, if browsing on the handset via browser and clicked on the linky, it would wipe the handset... yeah :D

Comment: @t0mm13b so typing secret code on Samsung devices in their native dialer app, will not send any broadcast? I have tried to use it in my app and registered a receiver for secret code.. on Samsung devices nothing happened, but on nexus 6p I see the number is getting clear yet the receiver is not triggered... on other devices it does work. any clues?

Comment: @Elior Samsung would have their own custom codes, they do not use the standard AOSP dialer app ;)

Comment: @t0mm13b thanks for your response :) 
so it seems that on my nexus, the receiver was not triggered after dialing secret code... looks like the native dialer app didn't send any broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you type '*#*#1234*#*#' , android extract numbers and send this Broadcast:

```
 sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE",
                            Uri.parse("android_secret_code://" + "1234")));
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me a long time ago..

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
String ussd = "*" + encodedHash + "123" + encodedHash;
startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)), 1);
```

Never tried again since then...

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. It is right for simple dial. But with secret code, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Look here, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9947615/1274911) could really help you.

Also, depending on what you're trying to get, the [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) class might help you. For example the IMEI of the device obtained by dialing *#06# can in your code be obtained by calling the `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` method.

You use it like this:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tm.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I really want to call it and many other secret code, for example *#*#3646#*#*

Comment: Just out of curiosity, may I ask what #*#3646#*# should do?

Comment: Well, it doesn't do anything on my phone. And Google doesn't seem to know it either. Anyway, I just think that if a user of the device can access something by dialing such special code, it would be weird if you couldn't access it from within your app using some class of the Android API.

Comment: Oh, I guess you meant \*#*#4636#*#\*. :)

Comment: I have question with code
*#*#0*#*#* ( LCD Test )
*#*#3264#*#* ( Version Of RAM )
*#*#2663#*#* ( Version Of Touch Screen )
*#*#0842#*#* ( Vibration Backlight Test )
*#*#2664#*#* ( Touch Screen Test )
*#*#0588#*#* ( Sensor Test )

Comment: I don't know, neither of these codes do anything on my phone... I have however tried to use `sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE", Uri.parse("android_secret_code://4636")));` from the answer I posted a link to in the first line of my answer and it worked. So I think that if all the other codes do something on some devices, this approach should work too. Please try it and let me know.