# Programmatically enter secret code like *#*#0011#*#* on Android

Tags: android, android-source

I have tried the solutions posted on

[Programmatically enter secret code like *#*#4636#*#* on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769166/programmatically-enter-secret-code-like-4636-on-android)
for my secret code #*#*0011#*#* like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);    
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*#*#0011#*#*"));
startActivity(intent);
```

This does not work!

also writing:-

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE"/> 
<data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="0011" />
```

In manifest is also not working

Unfortunately the above solutions do not provide any result and sticks to the dialer screen.
Is there something that is missing on my part?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically enter secret code like \*#\*#4636#\*#\* on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769166/programmatically-enter-secret-code-like-4636-on-android)

Comment: On that question there are other answers with other methods.  The SECRET_CODE intent should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the answer in the post you mentioned you'll notice that you are not using  `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`, but:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
in.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TestingSettings");
startActivity(in);
```