# How can we access or read measurement reports the measurement that the mobile phone carry out to a network operator?

Tags: android, iphone, telecommunication

A mobile phone can carry out power measurements
on the frequency currently in use, on UMTS neighbour frequencies and on GSM frequencies. It sends the results to the
network on the current link. A new link is established to the
neighbour cell that offers the best radio link quality.

[image]

Mobile phones perform measurements
for determining link quality in a radio
network and then send the results to
the network as UE measurement reports.
These reports provide vital information
for dynamic network planning and the
distribution of resources at the radio
interface (radio resource management).
The measurements and the mode of signalling are defined in the 3GPP specifications. Mobile phones have to be
tested to verify this functionality and the
stipulated measurement accuracy.
A mobile phone measures important
characteristics such as the power on
the frequency currently in use (intra-frequency measurements), on UMTS neighbour frequencies (inter-frequency measurements) and on GSM frequencies
(inter-RAT measurements; RAT: radio
access technology). These measurements are used to determine which
neighbour cell offers the best radio link
quality; a link is then set up to this cell.

During signalling, it is also possible to
query the current transmit power of the
mobile phone, the timing of its transmit
and receive signals, and the block error
ratio (BLER) of a data channel. To prepare for handover between UMTS cells,
the mobile phone can determine the
frame timing of its current link and of its
target cell.

How can we read the data that come out of the mobile phone using an android app? how can we read transmit power of the mobile phone device to be more specific?

Like tx level in the picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The interface into the telephony side of an Android device (assuming it supports telephony - i.e. not a tablet, TV STB etc) is the Android telephony API's:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary

You will see there are several which provide information around the strength of the signal and also the neighbouring cell strength.

[image]

[image]

The strengths here are the received signal strength. I am not aware at the time of writing of an API which will give the transmitted power. It may be useful to note, depending on your needs, that the transmit power is usually influenced by the receive strength - if a phone is near a tower and receiving a good signal it typically does not need to use as much power to transmit to that tower, and conversely if it is a long way away it typically needs more power to reach the tower. This is just a rough principle, but depending on your application it may be useful.

Comment: I've been working with telephony api for a while but what I want exactly is the data that the mobile devices carry out to a base station, such as transmit power of the phone device.

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to access it.

Comment: Yes, that is more aligned with the actual telephony part of a device - the part that speaks 'GSM' or LTE etc (or the actual 3GPP specs that correspond to these common names). That type of radio specific communication data is not usually needed by or shared with the 'app' side of the device.

Comment: BTW, if it is just for specific network testing rather than a general app, you can get dedicated client and network test equipment which will give you this data. I am guessing this is not what you want, but just in case.

Comment: Exactly, I want the app plays the network testing tool. Check the picture I added, shows that Android can read tx power level, and thats what i want.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a reliable way to get that programatically, that stays working over releases, but there are some techniques here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20248195/334402 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9769166/334402