# Launching android apps that uses codes(eg: *#1234#,*#06#) programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to launch apps that uses codes like *#06#, *#1234# (in samsung mobile phones) programmatically.

**I have tried the following methods but none of them works :**

1. sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE",Uri.parse("android_secret_code://1234")));
2. Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode("*#1234#")));
   startActivity(intent);

Please provide solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically enter secret code like \*#\*#4636#\*#\* on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769166/programmatically-enter-secret-code-like-4636-on-android)

Comment: Yeah i tried the mentioned solutions but not working on samsung mobile(for codes like *#1234#,  *#06#)

Comment: Well you should probably specify that in your question: does it work elsewhere, like the emulator?

Comment: Some codes are specific to samsung mobile phones only like *#1234#,*#9900# etc. I need a method to run these codes for launching the application.