# How can I dial secret code for my android application?

Tags: android, hidden

I'm developing an information application for my company and when I click the button, I wanna know my phone imei number but I can't do it because it can't allow hidden code such as *#06# (# means hidden code ). how can I use # character for an auto dial? Btw I'm not input any dial number it happens in the code automatically.

Comment: You should provide some specific code for us to be able to help you

Comment: You can do it without using the USSD code. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-get-the-devices-imei-esn-programmatically-in-android
The benefit is that you can use the result in your application.

If dialing is a requirement you can simply send an intent with action CALL and the encoded number as param. However I don't think that you can receive the result in your app with this method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically enter secret code like \*#\*#4636#\*#\* on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769166/programmatically-enter-secret-code-like-4636-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use TelephonyManager for this and use the permission READ_PHONE_STATE

you can find complete code from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-get-the-devices-imei-esn-programmatically-in-android)