# Programmatically Entering a Secret Code

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to enter secret codes programmatically on android in an app developed in Android Studio. I have been looking around and have not been able to find success with any method that I have seen yet. An example secret code that is not working is *#*#4636#*#*

I tried several answers posed in [Programmatically enter secret code like *#*#4636#*#* on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769166/programmatically-enter-secret-code-like-4636-on-android) without much success.

When I try the following it only inputs the number into the dialer, but the secret menu does not open.

```
String ussdCode = "*" +Uri.encode ("#")+"*"+Uri.encode ("#")+ "4636" + Uri.encode ("#")+"*"+Uri.encode ("#")+"*";
startActivity (new Intent ("android.intent.action.DIAL", Uri.parse ("tel:" + ussdCode)));
```

The following just makes the app crash

```
 sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.provider"));
 sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE", Uri.parse("android_secret_code://4636")));
```

This also makes the app crash

```
String secretCode = "4636";
String action = "android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE"; 
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android_secret_code://" + secretCode);
Intent intent = new Intent(action, uri);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This  only dials * and nothing else

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
dialIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: *#*#4636#*#*"));
startActivity(dialIntent);
```

How would I go about accomplishing this? I am working with Android 7.0+.

Edit: This is different from the mentioned question because none of the fixes that worked for the mentioned question 5 years ago no longer work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TestingSettings");
    startActivity(intent );
```

Comment: It does not work, the app only crashes as a result.